# In Python how functions on objects are still available while the class is not in scope?

Tags: python

For ex, still the method below

```
def func(value):
     class A:
         x = 2
         def __init__(self, value):
           A.x = value
         def print_x(self):
           print self.x
     return A(value)


a = func(4)
b = func(5)
```

Now you will find `a.print_x()` prints `4` . But `type(a)` will give `'instance'`. How does the print_x method is still attached to the object while the class is not in the scope ?

Secondly you will find that the value of `a.print_x()` doesnt changes while calling the func method again with new parameter `'5'`.

Does python creates  different class objects for the same class when func method is called ?

Comment: Yes, you create one class each time you call the function.

Comment: Do you mean `print A.x`?

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2.x, you should *always* make your classes inherit from `object` if they don't inherit from anything else. This is because about halfway through the lifetime of Python 2, all classes were placed in the same inheritance tree (so that everything is an object). For backwards compatibility, they can't force this to happen, so you have to do it yourself.

If you make `A` inherit from `object` then everything works. Note that the fact that `A` is not in the main scope says nothing about whether the interpreter knows about it. Indeed, the interpreter knows about lots of things that aren't in the main scope, since it knows about *everything in the program*!

You should be clear that the classes of `a` and `b` are *different* classes, both named `A`. You can do that, because they're not in the main scope so there's no name clash. There are therefore *two* class attributes called `x`, one on each version of the class `A`, and so there's no reason changing one should modify the other. If you want both instances of `A` to refer to the *same* class `A`, you should (of course) make `A` global!

I assume you meant to write `print A.x` instead of `print x`, so I fixed that for you.

---

Note that this is kind of a strange thing to do: you're dynamically creating a class with a class attribute `x`, instantiating it, and then returning the instance with the class variable. Are you sure you don't want to do `self.x = value` in `__init__`, and get rid of the line `x = 2`?

---

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f(value):
...     class A(object):
...             x = 2
...             def __init__(self, value):
...                     A.x = value
...             def print_x(self):
...                     print A.x
...     return A(value)
... 
>>> a = f(4)
>>> b = f(5)
>>> 
>>> a.print_x()
4
>>> b.print_x()
5
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x10e2e1ed0>
>>> A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x10e2e1ed0>
>>> b
<__main__.A object at 0x10e2e1fd0>
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>>
```

Comment: actually in this case A.x and self.x refer to the same variable as the instance doesnt have its own copy of x

Comment: sorry i didnt read your comment carefully yeah I meant A.x or self.x

Comment: @PlabanNayak Wrong: assigning to `self.x` _makes_ a instance variable =)

Comment: yeah i know that assigning to self.x makes it an instance variable rather i was talking only about printing self.x , in this case both A.x and self.x are same

Comment: @PlabanNayak No, they're not: there's no such thing as `self.x` in your example, because you haven't defined it. There's an `A.x`, but that's a _different_ variable.

Answer (score 0):

The class may not be "in scope", but the instances of that class (in your case, `a` and `b`) are. Since the reference to those objects still exist, they are not garbage-collected.

I suggest you read an introductory Python book for more clarification. Also, the documentation is pretty good.

Comment: `x` is _not_ an instance variable. It's a class variable -- but there are many classes floating around.

Comment: sorry, i only just noticed the assignment of A.x after reading your comment. Thanks. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The interpreter *does* have access to the class of `a` - it is `a.__class__`, and won't be GCd until all of its instances are. The reason `type(a)` gives `<type 'instance'>` has nothing to do with "undetermined class", and everything to do with `A` being an old-style class.